# Is there a trick to use Flask app teardown request?

Tags: python, flask

I need to run a function after every request, and it seems like the Flask decorator @app.teardown_request is the way to go, but although I am using the current app as app, I am getting the below error.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, current_app as app
from flask_login import login_required, current_user


# Set up a Blueprint
message_routes = Blueprint('messages', __name__, template_folder="templates")

        
@app.teardown_request
def session_clear(exception=None):
    app.cbdb.session.remove()
    if exception and app.cbdb.session.is_active:
        app.cbdb.session.rollback()
```

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to this problem is to not attempt to use the @app. decorators in the individual routes of the the Blueprint, but to use them in the **init**.py file, where you generally build you Flask app to begin with, the same as where you would put your 404 error controls and such, app.after_request, app.teardown_request and etc. will work there.